# jQuery - How to simulate an error event for ajaxSubmit

Tags: jquery

I use the ajaxSubmit to submit my form and would like to test the case where the event returns error.

```
  var options = {
    beforeSubmit: showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
    success:      showResponse, // post-submit callback 
    error:        printError,
    url:          '../validation.php'
  };
  $('#form1').submit(function () {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false;
  });
```

In other words, I need to know how to simulate an error event so that I can test the function printError.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

return an errorcode from your php script using the header statement. For example

```
header(‘HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden’);
```

or

```
header(‘HTTP/1.0 404 Not found’);
```

Comment: This is pretty much the same thing I suggested. I suggested pointing to an invalid URL and you suggested "faking" an invalid URL. I guess it's just a matter of which file you want to edit :) Good, clean solution.

Comment: you have more control over the type of error you want to simulate this way

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I still say, for the purposes of this post, it's apples and apples.

Answer (score 7):

.....try pointing the AJAX Request to an invalid URL? I think that'll work..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)'s [autoresponder](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/help/AutoResponder.asp) feature to intercept XHRs and simulate various error responses. This is especially helpful if you do not want to (or cannot) to meddle with server side code.